# Problem on JSON formating with a connected field of a lookup Column

Tags: lookup-column, column, json-formatting, help

In my List A I have a lookup column "CODE PROJET" and one connected lookup column "FIN RECONDCT" both coming from an other SharePoint list B.

[image]

On a field of the A List I try to do a JSON column formating with a test on "FIN RECONDCT" coming from B.

I get fine the value of "CODE PROJET" doing [$CODE_x0020_PROJET.lookupValue] but I never get the value of the connected field "FIN RECONDCT"

I tried different solutions. But whatever name I use to get the value, I get no error (in debug mode) and no value. I tried all these =>

[$FIN_x0020_RECONDCT.lookupValue]
[$CODE_x0020_PROJET:FIN_x0020_RECONDCT.lookupValue] [$CODE_x0020_PROJET.FIN_x0020_RECONDCT.lookupValue] [$CODE_x0020_PROJET:$FIN_x0020_RECONDCT.lookupValue] [$CODE_x0020_PROJET.$FIN_x0020_RECONDCT.lookupValue]

**Please can somebody help me?**

Answer (score 0):

See: [SharePoint Online: Using JSON Column Formatting to get lookup column value inside Form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297145/sharepoint-online-using-json-column-formatting-to-get-lookup-column-value-insid)

And: [JSON formatting column based upon added column of lookup column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297644/json-formatting-column-based-upon-added-column-of-lookup-column)

Ensure you are formatting like this
`[$YourLookupColumn.lookupValue]`

And that the lookup column is returning the expected data type.

If you’re still having trouble, provide more details about the lists and the exact error message you’re encountering.

Heres an example with a column called `Productgroup_x003a_Min`

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$Productgroup_x003a_Min]",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if (@currentField < [Productgroup_x003a_Min],'sp-field-severity--warning', '')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if (@currentField < [Productgroup_x003a_Min],'Error', '')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, the previous url talk about LookupColumn coming from the same list. Mine is coming from another list...

Comment: Are you certain you are using the correct column names? The internal name usually replaces spaces with _x0020_

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297644/json-formatting-column-based-upon-added-column-of-lookup-column

Comment: Yes I am. If you look to my first post you will see i tried with "_x0020_" also. In your exemple it does not look to be a lookup column coming from another list. Does it?